# Move y-axes label beneath below y-axes?

Tags: plotting

There are several other questions related to axes labeling; most of them can be solved by using `Labeled` or `FrameLabels` instead.

This question is specifically about the y-axes label.
For example the default is this:
[image]

How can I place the y label at the bottom (i.e. underneath -10)?

Comment: You may draw a plot without labels and draw a label separately, and then show it together with the plot, is it Ok with you?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Sure... but how do I get the positioning correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Show[{
  Plot[-x, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 11}, {-11, 0.3}}],
  Graphics[{Text[Style["y", 16, Italic], Scaled[{0.06, 0.044}]], 
    Text[Style["x", 16, Italic], Scaled[{0.99, 0.9}]]}]

  }]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 5):

```
Plot[-x, {x , 0, 10}, 
 Epilog -> (Style[Text[##], 16, "Panel"] & @@@ {{"x", {10.75, 0}}, {"y", {0, -10.75}}}),  
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]